# "Permissions denied" after moving to a new server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

We have moved our website to a new server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) which I had set up with 
ISPConfig 3.

### The Problem:

Everything works fine, but PHP gives me a "failed to open stream: Permission denied"-warning when trying to write new log-files to existing log-files.

I'm very insecure yet about playing around with stuff because I'm not quite familiar with Linux yet. 
Right now, all files and folders of my website have the owner "web1" from the group "client1". The permissions on the log-directory are the same as before (on the old host).

I'm aware that Apache (and PHP?) runs as its own user "www-data", so basically, I would have to tell my log-files and folders that it is ok to be read/written by this user, right?

### What I (would) have tried:

While researching, I bumped into [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/412995/permissions-and-groups-on-a-new-server) talking about creating a common group for the owner of the files (web1) and the apache-user (www-data).

I have also found the following instructions to do so:

```
//Create new group
$ sudo addgroup webdev

//Change the group of your web directory:
$ sudo chgrp -R webdev /var/www/
$ sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www/

//Set the guid bit on all folders in your web directory:
$ sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod +s {} \;

//Add Apache to the webdev group:
$ sudo usermod -a -G webdev www-data

//Add your user to the webdev group:
$ sudo usermod -a -G webdev <user_name>
```

But I haven't tried it yet because I'm not sure what

```
$ sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod +s {} \;
```

does. Is this even the correct approach to my problem?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not trying to talk down, just breaking it all down.

```
sudo - run this command as a super user
find - look for something... 
/var/www - ...in the /var/www directory...
-type d  - ...that is a directory...
-exec chmod +s - ...and executes a chmod (change mode) +s (set the user bit) ...
{} - ...for every directory you find...
\; - and end the command.
```

now the commands listed above look fine if that is what you want to do. Creating a common group with apache and others. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually makes sense :-D I guess I was confused by the `+s`-parameter (I olny know things like `chmod u+r`). I'm actually not sure if this is what I want because I'm not familiar enough with Linux to figure out what exactly the problem is. My assumption was that "www-data" can't write to the property of "web1" because it is not allowed to, but if I put them both in one group with read+write permissions it should solve the problem - right?

Comment: Correct. By being in the same group they can write to things owned by the same group even if the owner is different like say root.